# Angular Google Maps doesn't render

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm trying to get [AGM](https://angular-maps.com) to work in my Ionic 2 application.

**app.module.ts**

```
...

import { AgmCoreModule } from '@agm/core';
import { DirectionsMapDirective } from '../components/directions-map';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    ...
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
    AgmCoreModule.forRoot({
      apiKey: '<api key>',
      libraries: ['places']
    })
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    ...
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    DirectionsMapDirective,
    { provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler }
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**map.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-requests',
  templateUrl: 'requests.html'
})
export class MapPage {
  lat: number = 51.678418;
  lng: number = 7.809007;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {}

}
```

**map.html**

```
<ion-content>
  <sebm-google-map [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng">
    <sebm-google-map-marker [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng"></sebm-google-map-marker>
  </sebm-google-map>
</ion-content>
```

When run, I get the following error:

> Template parse errors: Can't bind to 'latitude' since it isn't a known
>   property of 'sebm-google-map'.

Answer (score 1):

You need to import the directive:

```
import {SebmGoogleMap, SebmGoogleMapMarker} from 'angular2-google-maps/core';
```

And add them to your `@Component` declaration:

```
@Component({
 selector: 'my-map-cmp',
 directives: [SebmGoogleMap, SebmGoogleMapMarker],
 template: `
   <sebm-google-map [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng" [zoom]="zoom">
     <sebm-google-map-marker [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng" [label]="'M'">
     </sebm-google-map-marker>
   </sebm-google-map>
 `
})
```

Answer (score 0):

SrAxi pointed me in the right direction, however in the current Angular version (4.x), Components cannot have directives I believe.

What I discovered is that `angular2-google-maps` was only recently renamed to `@agm`. If you import AGM using `@agm` (as in the tutorial on Github), the names of the selectors have been changed but the documentation has not been updated.

This is the only documentation of the new selectors: https://github.com/SebastianM/angular-google-maps/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#100-beta0---green-zebra-2017-04-09

In my example, I needed up update `map.html` to:

```
<agm-map [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng">
  <agm-marker [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng"></agm-marker>
</agm-map>
```